# Pandas union of 3 columns of text

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a union of 3 columns from a dataframe. The 3 columns are of type object.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Dog | Monkey |
| Dog | Horse | Cat |

I want a union of columns A,B,C and I am expecting this result -

```
List A = [Cat,Dog,Horse,Monkey]
```

My naive approach:

```
df['union'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A'].union(x['B']), axis=1)
```

This is the error I get:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'union'

Please tell me how to get this result.

Comment: `df.stack().unique().to_list()`, if your dataframe has more than the three columns, replace `df` with `df[['A','B','C']]`.

Comment: another approach `set(df.to_numpy().flatten())`

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a `set`, which you can get by using:

```py
set(df.to_numpy().ravel())  # {'Cat', 'Dog', 'Horse', 'Monkey'}
```

Python sets support operations like `union` with another set.

To compare the suggested solutions, here are the timings using `timeit` on my machine, ordered by speed:

```py
set(df.to_numpy().flatten())           # 5.78 µs ± 682 ns per loop

set(df.to_numpy().ravel())             # 5.93 µs ± 620 ns per loop

np.unique(df.values.ravel()).tolist()  # 14.3 µs ± 1.79 µs per loop

df.stack().unique().tolist()           # 517 µs ± 124 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do : `np.unique(df.values.ravel()).tolist()`